# Angular, comparación de valor (de celda de archivo excel subido) y atributo de clase

Tags: angular, typescript

Quiero comparar en Angular el valor obtenido de una celda de un archivo excel con un atributo de una clase y no logro hacerlo, siempre me da false.

En angular subo un archivo excel, lo leo y lo paso a una variable de esta forma

```
fileUpload(Event: any) {


    let selectedFile = Event.target.files[0];
    let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
    fileReader.onloadend = (Event) => {
      console.log(Event);
      let binaryData = Event.target?.result;
      let workbook = XLSX.read(fileReader.result, { type: 'binary' });
      let sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames;
      this.resultadosCarrera = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(
        workbook.Sheets[sheetNames[0]]

      );
      
      console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetNames[0]]));
      this.resultadosCarrera2=XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetNames[0]]);

      this.recorrerPilotos()
    }


  }
```

Previamente leí y recorrí un archivo de esta manera

```
public traerPilotos(){

    this.pilotServicio.obtenerPilotos().subscribe((dato:Pilotos[]) =>{this.pilot = dato;
    });


  }
```

y acá es donde comparo los dos campos para ver si el nombre del piloto de la tabla de excel existe en la tabla Pilotos de la base de datos, pero siempre da false aunque los nombres sean los mismos

```
public recorrerPilotos() {
    for (let posicion of this.resultadosCarrera2) {
       this.encontro = false;
       console.log("excel:", posicion.Piloto)
       for (let pil of this.pilot) {

        if (pil.nombrePiloto === posicion.Piloto) {
        console.log ("Piloto: ", pil.nombrePiloto , "  Excel: ", posicion.Piloto);
         this.encontro = true;
         console.log("encontro: ", this.encontro)
          this.pil2 = this.pil;
       }
      }
```

Comment: Como concejo: tú tienes un par de console.log justamente en la parte que NO entra. Lo ideal sería que pusieras esos console.log en donde SI entra, para que pudieras depurar si efectivamente si los datos que estás evaluando responden a lo que necesitas

Comment: Gracias Yussef por responder, tenía esos console.log , los borré antes de subirlo acá. Y si, ahí ví que aún cuando los nombres coinciden no cambia a true la variable encontro

Comment: Probaste con dos iguales == en vez de los 3 === que tienes el if??

Comment: Si, ya probé también eso

Answer (score -1):

Ya encontré cual era el problema.

Estaba comparando contra this.pil.nombrePiloto en lugar de comparar contra pil.nombrePiloto.

Comment: Si subes el código y ni siquiera subes el código real que tienes... cómo vamos a poder ayudarte? Porque en tu pregunta no comparas con `this.pil.nombrePiloto` si no con `pil.nombrePiloto` ergo, tu código de la pregunta **NO** tiene errores...